# Change the value of an embedded dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have a dictionary like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List<string>, bool>> dictionary= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List<string>, bool>>();
```

This dictionary is getting filled with the boolean value, false as default.

I want to change the boolean value in a specific row (in the embedded dictionary) to true; to be like this.

```
  dictionary["cell-22"] = {"cell-22", {["first property", "second property"]}, true}
```

Comment: Using a `List<string>` for a `Dictionary` key doesn't make much sense as it's going to hash on the reference of the `List` and not on the values in the list unless you also create a `IEqualityComparer` to do that for you and pass tn in when you create the dictionary.

Comment: If you need a key that contains exactly 2 string values you can do `Dictionary<(string, string), bool>` or `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, bool>` instead.

Comment: This is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). This dictionary seems very very wrong. What is it supposed to do and be used like ?

Comment: `List`s are reference objects, that means that equality will only work *for the same object instance* so it will not work as you expect.

Comment: Franck, I need to store the information of every grid-cell in a Unity scene. The key is the name of the cell, while in the embedded dictionary, in the key (list) I will hold the objects that contain and in the value (bool) if it is on fire or not,

Comment: Wouldn't for a grid something like `public class GridCell { public Dictionary<string, bool> properties = new Dictionary<string, bool>(); }` and then `public GridCell[,] grid = new GridCell[width, height];` be way better?

Comment: What’s the 22 in your example represent? You only have a string list and a boil. So no you can’t pick 22. It would have to be the same string list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary but **not** with a `List<string>`! You would always need the **exact same List reference** in order to access the according element from the `Dictionary`.

Rather make the inner one only a `Dictionary<string, bool>` for mapping **one key** to **one value**.

---

For reasons of readability and maintainability instead of nesting these kind of collection types I would rather create proper wrapper classes like e.g.

```
public class GridCell 
{ 
    public Dictionary<string, bool> Properties = new Dictionary<string, bool>(); 
}
```

And then since you mentioned a grid instead of accesing certain fields via string keys I would rather use it in an actual "grid" or two-dimensional array like

```
public GridCell[,] Grid = new GridCell[width, height];
public List<string> GridProperties = new List<string>();
```

for intializing it you would once run e.g.

```
for(var i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        var newGridCell = new GridCell();
        foreach(var property in GridProperties)
        {
            newGridCell.properties.Add(property, false);
        }
        Grid[i, j] = newGridCell;
    }
}
```

and then you could access any of the properties like

```
var hasProperty = Grid[2,2].Properties[propertyName];

Grid[2,2].Properties[propertyName] = true;
```

and for setting multiple properties at once rather implement a method like

```
public class GridCell 
{ 
    public Dictionary<string, bool> Properties = new Dictionary<string, bool>(); 

    public void SetProperties(List<string> properties, bool value)
    {
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            // Either updates the entry if it exists already
            // or adds a new entry for this key
            Properties[property] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the grid class go

```
public void SetProperties(int gridX, int gridY, List<string> properties, bool value)
{
    // creates the new field if it didn't exist so far
    if(Grid[gridX, gridX] == null)) Grid[gridX, gridY] = new GridCell();

    Grid[gridX, gridY].SetProperties(properties, value);
}
```

---

Of course you could still do the same using only a dictionary, just as before the inner one **not** with `List<string>` but only `string` as the key

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>> Grid = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();
```

then after initializing it accordingly you can access a specific value like

```
var hasProperty = Grid[indexName][propertyName];

Grid[indexName][propertyName] = true;
```

for setting multiple values at once you should rather implement your own method like e.g.

```
public void SetProperties(string indexName, List<string> properties, bool value)
{
    // creates the new field if it didn't exist so far
    if(!Grid.ContainsKey(indexName)) Grid[indexName] = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    foreach(var property in properties)
    {
        // This either updates an existing property entry
        // or creates a new one if it didn't exist so far
        Grid[indexName][property] = value;
    }
}
```

---

I would prefer the solution on the top for better maintainability. You can easily implement more methods into the `GridCell` class or change and extend the existing ones without affecting anything on the outside too much. You can also easily separate (decouple) the grid related stuff into one additional class without e.g. cluttering a `MonoBehaviour` component with too many methods.

With the second approach you will terminate with one super powerful class that does the whole work inside this nested `Dictionary`.

Answer (score -3):

Your dictionary definition may be right (not likely but difficult to say definitavely without better question clarification).

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List<string>, bool>> dictionary= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List<string>, bool>>();
```

Having a key in the scond dictionary looks very unlikely though.
I suspect this is what you meant.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<(string, bool)> dictionary= new Dictionary<string,List<(string, bool)>();
```

Comment: `Dictionary<string, List, bool>` makes even less sense as a dictionary only has a generic type of the key and value, there is no third generic type.

Comment: I was still editing you guys were quick to comment ;)

Comment: Don't post until you have properly formatted your answer or things like these will happen ;) (I removed my downvote, now it makes sense)

Comment: It is just the nature of the web if you fully formulate your answers  and get them right (as I used to do) then the accepted answer is posted 10 minitues before you have finished writing your most of the time. I was just throwing an answer together to get the couple of points I needed to be able to comment so that I could help people rathere then be in the rat race for reputation points